# OpenGL gl_Position z-range and depth buffer range

Tags: opengl, coordinates, depth

Am I correct that the OpenGL depth buffer has values between 0 and 1 while the z component of gl_Position is between -1 and 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `gl_Position.z` should be between [-1, 1] after dividing `gl_Position.w`, otherwise will be clipped.
OpenGL will map [-1, 1] to [0, 1], use `glDepthRange(near, far)` can change the default value.